# TFX-CLI: is there a way to download task.json from the "tfx" server?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Is there a way to download the `task.json` from the "tfx" server with `tfx-cli`?

I wanted to recover a task.json that we have uploaded in tfx by using the command:

```
tfx build tasks upload –task.path ./task.json
```

I tried to find if we'd have any "download" command in `tfx build tasks --help` that is what I got:

```
TFS Cross Platform Command Line Interface v0.7.11
Copyright Microsoft Corporation

Available commands and command groups in tfx / build / tasks:
 - create: Create files for new Build Task
 - delete: Delete a Build Task.
 - list: Get a list of build tasks
 - upload: Upload a Build Task.
```

As we can see I could not find any "download" command. Would someone have an idea how we could do a download of a task.json from tfx server?

Answer (score 2):

As you said, there is no "download" option in the tf-cli.

But, you can get the `task.json` from uploaded extension with just download the `.vsix` file and open it:

1)

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

Open the file with WinRar/Zip:

[image]

4)

Open `task` folder, you will see there the `task.json`:

[image]